# How to debug generic React Native error messages on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

Unless I enable debugging (Esc > Cmd+D > Debug JS Remotely) then I see this error:

`Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module`

This also means that I'm unable to view the bundled app on device. If I try to view the app on device, but still use the dev server (remembering to use an IP address in `AppDelegate.m` instead of `localhost`) then I instead get this error:

`WebSocket connection failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused"`

even though I've verified that I can open the dev server URL in a browser on the device.

I'm not an iOS developer, so maybe this is really obvious, but how do I go about debugging why these errors are happening, or just not having these errors in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be App Transport Security that was added in iOS 9. Please see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#app-transport-security for reference. You have to add the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads entry to your Info.plist yourself if you didn't use the React Native CLI to generate your project.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be that too, but already checked to make sure I had the right setting, and I did.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't really answer the 'How do I debug these kinds of generic errors' question, I've found out that in my case the problem was that I created my app using an older version of RN (maybe 0.26?) that had a bug in the scaffolding code it creates (which I stupidly ignored at the time when I found i could work around it by enabling debugging) and updating to newer versions of the app hasn't fixed the issue because that doesn't cause the scaffolding to be updated. By creating a fresh app under RN 0.29, and copying my code into it, everything is now working as expected.